# Problem pulling data from website in .NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebresponse, streamreader, web-scraping

I have written a web scraping program to go to a list of pages and write all the html to a file.  The problem is that when I pull a block of text some of the characters get written as '�'.  How do I pull those characters into my text file?  Here is my code:

```
string baseUri = String.Format("http://www.rogersmushrooms.com/gallery/loadimage.asp?did={0}&blockName={1}", id.ToString(), name.Trim());

// our third request is for the actual webpage after the login.
HttpWebRequest request =
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseUri);
request.Method = "GET";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)";
//get the response object, so that we may get the session cookie.
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

// and read the response
string page = reader.ReadToEnd();

StreamWriter SW;
string filename = string.Format("{0}.txt", id.ToString());
SW = File.AppendText("C:\\Share\\" + filename);

SW.Write(page);

reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

Comment: Encoding issues. Check out SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700638/characters-in-string-changed-after-downloading-html-from-the-internet/2700707#2700707

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify your encoding in this line:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

and

`File.AppendText("C:\\Share\\" + filename);` uses [UTF-8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You're saving a page named `loadimage` to a text file.  Are you sure that's really all text?

Either way, you can save yourself a lot of code by using `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile()`.

Answer (score 0):

Specify Unicode encoding, like so:

```
New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Text.Encoding.UTF8)
```

..same for the StreamWriter