# C# and HtmlAgilityPack encoding problem

Tags: c#, encoding, html-agility-pack

```
WebClient GodLikeClient = new WebClient();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument GodLikeHTML = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

GodLikeHTML.Load(GodLikeClient.OpenRead("www.alfa.lt");
```

So this code returns: "Skaitytojo klausimas psichologui: kas lemia homoseksualumÄ…? - NaujienÅ³ portalas Alfa.lt" instead of "Skaitytojo klausimas psichologui: kas lemia homoseksualumą? - Naujienų portalas Alfa.lt".

This webpage is encoded in 1257 (baltic), but `textBox1.Text = GodLikeHTML.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;` returns the distorted text - baltic diacritics are transformed into some weird several characters long strings :(

And yes, I've tried the HtmlAgilityPack forums. They do suck.

P.S. I'm no programmer, but I work on a community project and I really need to get this code working. Thanks ;}

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually the page is encoded with UTF-8.

```
GodLikeHTML.Load(GodLikeClient.OpenRead("http://www.alfa.lt"), Encoding.UTF8);
```

will work.

Or you could use the code in my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700638) which detects encoding from http headers or meta tags, en re-encodes properly. (It also supports gzip to minimize your download).

With the download class your code would look like:

```
HttpDownloader downloader = new HttpDownloader("http://www.alfa.lt",null,null);
GodLikeHTML.LoadHtml(downloader.GetPage());
```

Comment: Yup, that did the job :D 
Wow, quite simple, isn't it.
Thanks!

Comment: many thanks, got crazy characters like á or whatever, now it is working fine

Comment: Dehell is GodLikeHTML? Is this a synonym or am I actually looking for class with that name?

Comment: It's a variable from the original question

Comment: How to use a Proxy and DefaultCredentials with your class?

Comment: @PierreLebon I suggest you take a look at the availble properties of the HttpWebRequest class and you will be amazed :)

Comment: I made an overload on the constructor and added into the get page request. but now future reader will have a solid hint on how to do it. Because when fighting against encoding you can miss simple thing.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar encoding problems.  I fixed it, in the most current version of HtmlAgilityPack, by adding the following to my WebClient initialization.

```
var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
htmlWeb.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
var doc = htmlWeb.Load("www.alfa.lt");
```

Comment: Best answer (why to use webclient when you can do it by only using HTMLAgilityPack

Answer (score 6):

UTF8 didn't work for me, but after setting the encoding like this, most pages i was trying to scrape worked just wel:

```
web.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

Perhaps it might help someone.

Comment: Thanks! It was weird, I had been debugging my program to do HtmWeb web = new HtmlWeb(); then doc = web.Load(nextPageUrl); and it had stopped working. I had been testing for several days. Why would it stop working? I had a bug that threw a custom exception. But ever after that, even after restarting my app from debugger several times it was giving me that weird error. Your solution fixed mine. I was looking for  a way, but didn't see it.

Answer (score 5):

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument(); 
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(YourUrl).GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default); //put your encoding            
 doc.Load(reader);
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

if all of those post doesn't work, Just use this: `WebUtility.HtmlDecode("Your html text");`

Answer (score 1):

try to change that to `GodLikeHTML.Load(GodLikeClient.OpenRead("www.alfa.lt"), Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));`

Comment: sorry, I've misguided you - it was encoded in utf. 
Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to remove the need to know anything about encoding for me:

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the url to pull html documents from: ");

            string url = Console.ReadLine();

            HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();

            var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            var response = request.GetResponse();

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                document.LoadHtml(reader.ReadToEnd());
            } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
 HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.sina.com.cn");
HttpWebResponse response =(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
long len = response.ContentLength;
byte[] barr = new byte[len]; 
response.GetResponseStream().Read(barr, 0, (int)len); 
response.Close();
string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(barr); 
var encod = doc.DetectEncodingHtml(data);
string convstr = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Encoding.Convert(encod, Encoding.Unicode, barr));
doc.LoadHtml(convstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler (`WebClient` seems not to have any `OverrideEncoding` feature):

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Encoding  = Encoding.UTF8;
    // do whatever you want...
}
```

(works for me in .NET Framework 4.8)