# HtmlAgilityPack - How to set custom encoding when loading pages

Tags: c#, wpf, encoding, load, html-agility-pack

Is it possible to set custom encoding when loading pages with the method below?

```
HtmlWeb hwWeb = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument hd = hwWeb.load("myurl");
```

I want to set encoding to "iso-8859-9".

I use C# 4.0 and WPF.

Edit: [The question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lt-LT/csharpgeneral/thread/b2733aa5-99dc-4bcc-a3b8-ea0754f494e0) has been answered on MSDN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you could try overriding the encoding in the `HtmlWeb` object.

Try this:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb
{
    AutoDetectEncoding = false,
    OverrideEncoding = myEncoding,
};
var doc = web.Load(myUrl);
```

Note: It appears that the `OverrideEncoding` property was added to HTML agility pack in revision 76610 so it is not available in the current release v1.4 (66017).  The next best thing to do would be to read the page manually with the encodings overridden.

Comment: htmlagilitypack does not recognize OverrideEncoding

Comment: Ah, sorry.  It looks like the `OverrideEncoding` property of `HtmlWeb` is new and not in v1.4.  I was using the latest version as reference ([source](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/91044#1336968)).  I suppose the best option right now would be to load the page manually.

Comment: i also would like to use latest. where can i download

Comment: You would have to download the [latest source](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/91044#) and compile it.  It doesn't seem like they've released any precompiled versions that has this change.  I might be able to do that for you but am having internet connection problems as the moment so I'd be of little help.  Also, goes without saying but take care in using it as it might not be release-ready.

Comment: I guess you could just open the solution in visual studio and hit compile.  If it doesn't work, I'll have to get back to you on that, when my connection stabilizes and I'm able to verify what you would need to do to get it working.

Comment: yes i did that but still does not recognize it. very interesting. i did 1.4.0_beta2

Comment: No you don't want the beta build, you'll want the source that I linked to above ([link](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/91044#)) and compile that.  If you're still having problems, I'll try to compile it myself and upload somewhere.

Comment: Yes, the version found in the trunk is what you'll want to compile (make sure it is the "Release" version).  I just did this and uploaded it [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?293fzu4v3ib367u).  You could try out this version if you want or compile it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"));
        var html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        document.LoadHtml(html);
    }
}
```

This is a simple version of the solution answered <s>[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lt-LT/csharpgeneral/thread/b2733aa5-99dc-4bcc-a3b8-ea0754f494e0)</s> (for some reasons it got deleted)

Answer (score 0):

A decent answer is over here which handles auto-detecting the encoding as well as some other nifty features:

[C# and HtmlAgilityPack encoding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452343/c-sharp-and-htmlagilitypack-encoding-problem)