# Characters replaced by question mark when parsing html

Tags: c#, encoding, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to read a parse a html file and extract some text:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
            var document = webGet.Load("http://port.ro/");

            var programs = from program in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                           where program.Name == "a" && program.Attributes["href"] != null && program.InnerText.Trim().Length > 0
                           select program.InnerText ;

            foreach (string s in programs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

My problem is that the website contains characters like `à` and when I print them, they are replaced by `?`.

What should I need to do so when I print the text the character `à` its replaced by `a` or print it like `à` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# unicode string output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055659/c-sharp-unicode-string-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using or set the encoding as required for the site. This should help you get the proper text

> <del>var document = webGet.Load("http://port.ro/", Encoding.UTF8);//check your encoding</del>

Above one is for htmldocument

for HtmlWeb
[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883693/htmlagilitypack-how-to-set-custom-encoding-when-loading-pages):

```
var web = new HtmlWeb
{
    AutoDetectEncoding = false,
    OverrideEncoding = myEncoding,
};
var doc = web.Load(myUrl);
```

Comment: can I use that for the second argument ? I get "invalid arguments"

Comment: Now it doesn't know about OverrideEncoding, without it I get the same results

Comment: seems to be an old version, check out the comments in the link and perhaps you should use the latest version

Comment: Yep the latest version its working, btw do you know what encoding should I use so I dont get 'à' characters, only 'a' ?

Answer (score 1):

In `HtmlAgility` there is property to set stream encoding (normaly it should autodetect encoding ) but maybe not working for your page.. (wrong meta tags etc..)