# .Net HtmlAgilityPack Turkish character encoding issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, character-encoding, turkish

I have problem with HtmlAgilityPack Turkish charackter encoding.[image]

Comment: [What encoding are you using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883693/htmlagilitypack-how-to-set-custom-encoding-when-loading-pages) when you load the document?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you I solve this issue with the following code

```
  string url = "blabla";
  var Webget = new HtmlWeb();
  Webget.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  var doc = Webget.Load(url);
```