# Decode special characters when parsing html mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

In my mvc web application I am trying to parse a html document. It seems to work fine but the only issue is that it gives me special charters and not parse characters like æ,å,ø etc correctly.

Here is my code

```
var html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://cricketforbundet.no/index.php/en/klubber"));
var root = html.DocumentNode;
var p = root.Descendants("table").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("tr").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().ChildNodes.Where(i=>i.Name == "td").FirstOrDefault().InnerText;
```

I get *BjÃ¸rvikaÂ Cricket Klubb* in *p* where as I should get *Bjørvika Cricket Klubb*.

Any thoughts? I am using HtmlAgilityPack to parse HTML in ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `load` instead of `LoadHtml` and make sure use `UTF8` encoding

```
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
        html.Load(webClient.OpenRead("http://cricketforbundet.no/index.php/en/klubber"), Encoding.UTF8);
        var root = html.DocumentNode;
        var p = root.Descendants("table").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("tr").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().ChildNodes.Where(i => i.Name == "td").FirstOrDefault().InnerText;
```

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3452343/3254920)