# Using WebClient.DownloadString() return odd characters sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Characters in string changed after downloading HTML from the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700638/characters-in-string-changed-after-downloading-html-from-the-internet)

To reproduce my issue have a look a the following code snippet:

```
const string url = "http://serienjunkies.org/serie/glee/";
var webclient = new WebClient();
var source = webclient.DownloadString(url);
Console.WriteLine(source.Substring(0, 200);
```

Sometimes (with absolutely the same code) I get the correct html source and othertimes just an unreadable string with odd characters. If you get the one - wait some seconds up to one minute - then you will get the other.

Expected result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
...
```

The other result (copy, paste from cmd):

```
▼      ♥????????y]2?? em§?.f♦∟3Hf??J?XRM*???%??9 Gf¶##R1p?-??;?♥???♀???U?M?I?s &?#9???⌂?????fg????o????????????;}-????v⌂???^go????????zu???????tD?u^M?h:?
...
```

Thank you.

Kind regards, Danny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the server is delivering content in a compressed (GZip) format.

The answer here [Characters in string changed after downloading HTML from the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700638/characters-in-string-changed-after-downloading-html-from-the-internet) will give you a replacement downloader that will handle compressed and uncompressed files.